# Why Senku and Taiju revived from petrification when everybody else needed Senku's formula to revive?

Tags: dr.stone

People who survived petrification were revived using Senku's formula, with the exception of Senku and Taiju. How were they able to revive without any formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hypothesized by Senku that both he and Taiju were revived because they remained largely awake throughout the petrification.

They both were revived due to the presence of nitric acid from the guano cave. This presumably took time and a significant amount of acid to release them. Reviving normal people takes the stronger etching compound Nital.

However, since we know both Senku and Taiju were shown to be actively thinking and concentrating on a particular goal while petrified, this may account for how they were revived more easily than, say, the birds.

Answer (score 1):

Taiju at least break the stone with the water drops from the cave he was in... and this water is the base of the Senku's formula.

It is explained by the Senku itself in the 2º episode of the anime (From memory i think is the 2º episode, but maybe id the third).

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga Stack Exchange. While this answer might be correct, could you add some sources/references to back up this? Like, the episode number or manga chapter. Thank you.

Comment: for sure! i just edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

We know that for waking up X needs  the presence of netric acid and some "energy of thinking "(that's the case of senko and taiju) but senku woke up outside the cave it means that the nitric acid didn't help
I just watched the 6 first episodes i actually  need an answer to continue watching and to understand in some way